# Using multiple classes in Cucumber glue option package

Tags: java, testing, cucumber

I have a problem using the glue option when running Cucumber tests. Here's my test runner class:

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(features="src/test/java/com/xcase/tests/cucumber/features/api/APITest.feature",glue={"com.xcase.tests.cucumber.stepdefinitions.api"})
public class APIRunnerTest {

}
```

I run the tests along these lines:

`mvn clean test -Dtest=APIRunnerTest`

If I put all of my step definitions in a single class in the glue package, `com.xcase.tests.cucumber.stepdefinitions.api.FirstSteps`, then my tests run fine.

If I add an empty class to the `com.xcase.tests.cucumber.stepdefinitions.api` package, say `com.xcase.tests.cucumber.stepdefinitions.api.SecondSteps`,then my tests run fine. However, if I modify `SecondSteps` to extend `FirstSteps`, then my tests stop running completely! Why is that?

This is a problem for me because I'd like to put some shared step definitions and fields in a base step definition class and then have multiple classes that extend the base class. How should I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> However, if I modify `SecondSteps` to extend `FirstSteps`, then my tests stop running completely! Why is that?

You now have two classes that declare steps. And because `SecondSteps` extends `FirstSteps`, `SecondSteps` will declare the same exact steps as `FirstSteps`. So Cucumber can't decide which steps should be run.

> This is a problem for me because I'd like to put some shared step definitions and fields in a base step definition class and then have multiple classes that extend the base class. How should I do this?

If you want to share information between steps you should use [a world object](https://cucumber.io/docs/cucumber/state/). The documentation uses ruby but after adding `cucumber-pico` as a dependency it works the same way in Java. For a dated tutorial check [Sharing state between steps in Cucumber-JVM using PicoContainer](http://www.thinkcode.se/blog/2017/04/01/sharing-state-between-steps-in-cucumberjvm-using-picocontainer)

Comment: Thanks - this is exactly what I needed to be explained!