# How to correctly intercept @Before and @After methods in cucumber + JUnit project?

Tags: java, junit, cucumber

I try to switch from the TestNG to the Cucumber + JUnit, but can't intercept tests before/after suit.
Also, I can't add an error interception.

Project structure:

```
my-app/
├─ src/
│  ├─ test/
│  │  ├─ java/
│  │  │  ├─ LoginTest.java
│  │  │  ├─ BaseTest.java
│  │  ├─ resources/
│  │  │  ├─ login.feature
```

- LoginTest:

```java
@CucumberOptions(
        features = {"classpath:loginform.feature"}
)
public class LoginTest extends BaseTest{
    @Given("^The login page opened \"([^\"]*)\"$")
    public void openTheHomePage(String url) {
        System.out.println("Start");
    }
}
```

- BaseTest:

```java
    @RunWith(Cucumber.class)
    public class BaseTest {

    @Before
    public void init(){
        System.out.println("Before);
    }

    public void quit(){
        System.out.println("After");
    }
}
```

When I use `import org.junit.Before;` nothing happened, when I use `import io.cucumber.java.Before;` I get the compile error:

```
Suppressed: io.cucumber.java.InvalidMethodException: You're not allowed to extend classes that define Step Definitions or hooks. class slotgentesting.steps.LoginTest extends class slotgentesting.steps.BaseTest
```

## Also I try to intercept TestCases with `ConcurrentEventListener`:

```java
public class MyTestListener implements ConcurrentEventListener {
    @Override
    public void setEventPublisher(EventPublisher publisher) {
        publisher.registerHandlerFor(TestCaseFinished.class, this::handleTestCaseFinished);
    }

    private void handleTestCaseFinished(TestCaseFinished event) {
        TestCase testCase = event.getTestCase();
        Result result = event.getResult();
        Status status = result.getStatus();
        Throwable error = result.getError();
        String scenarioName = testCase.getName();
        String id = "" + testCase.getUri() + testCase.getLine();
        System.out.println("Testcase " + id + " - " + status.name());
    }
}
```

But the code also did not execute there.
I can't understand how to use such listeners, when I even haven't `@Listeners` annotation like in `TestNG`

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57131198/using-multiple-classes-in-cucumber-glue-option-package/57131960#57131960 it has the same problem caused by extending a class with step definitions.

Comment: @M.P.Korstanje thanks a lot, but there aren't about Before/After hooks - there are about scenario leaking. The manual even mentioned in first steps - "make sure you clear your DB in Before step" - I can't implement Before step

Answer (score 1):

Your setup is wrong in a few ways and this means that your project will never work. However you are too focused on getting to your objective to see it.

Follow these rules and you'll get closer to fixing it. Understanding will come later.

1. Never use `extends`.
2. Have a single class, and only that one class, anotated with *both* `@RunWith` and `@CucumberOptions`.
3. Do not use Cucumbers `@Given/When/Then/Before/After` in the class annotated with `@RunWith`.
4. Only use JUnits `@BeforeClass/AfterClass` in the class annotated with `@RunWith`.
5. Do not use event listeners for anything but reporting. So in your case, do not use them.

---

Alternatively delete your code and start with a new project by following the [10 minute tutorial](https://docs.cucumber.io/docs/guides/10-minute-tutorial/) and then use Cucumbers `@BeforeAll/AfterAll` annotation.

https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/main/java#beforeall--afterall

```
package io.cucumber.example;

import io.cucumber.java.AfterAll;
import io.cucumber.java.BeforeAll;

public class StepDefinitions {

    @BeforeAll
    public static void beforeAll() {
        // Runs before all scenarios
    }

    @AfterAll
    public static void afterAll() {
        // Runs after all scenarios
    }
}
```

This also means you'll be using JUnit 5 instead of JUnit 4.

https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/main/junit-platform-engine#cucumber-junit-platform-engine

Comment: So, do I need to clean and reinitialize driver in the each class? I hoped make this in the one parent-class

Comment: The second paragraph in this answer should answer that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57131198/using-multiple-classes-in-cucumber-glue-option-package/57131960#57131960

Comment: And updated docs for pico container are here: https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/main/picocontainer

Comment: The cucumber documentation says that it is not [recommended to use @BeforeClass/AfterClass](https://cucumber.io/docs/cucumber/api/?lang=java#:~:text=Cucumber%20supports%20JUnits,After%20hooks.) Instead, you should use @Before/After... Does it mean that we need to add those on every single step definition file?

Answer (score 0):

Feature file:

Feature: Login

Test Login functionality

Scenario Outline:

1. Login to application with valid user name and password
2. Given User is on login page
3. When The user logins to app with username as `<username>` and password as `<password>`
4. Then The user should login successfully and is brought to the inventory page

   Examples:

```
      | username      | password     |
      | standard_user | secret_sauce |
```

Step definition:

```
    import io.cucumber.java.After;
    import io.cucumber.java.Before;
    import io.cucumber.java.en.Given;
    import io.cucumber.java.en.Then;
    import io.cucumber.java.en.When;
    
    public class SauceDemoStepDefinition {
    
        @Before
        public void setup() throws Exception {
            System.out.println("Before");
        }
    
        @After
        public void tearDown() throws Exception {
            System.out.println("After");
        }
    
        @Given("^User is on login page$")
        public void user_is_on_login_page() throws Exception {
            System.out.println("Launch login page");
        }
    
        @When("The user logins to app with username as {string} and password as {string}")
        public void the_user_logins_to_app_with_username_as_and_password_as(String username, String password)
                throws Exception {
            System.out.println("Login to app");
        }
    
        @Then("The user should login successfully and is brought to the inventory page")
        public void the_user_should_login_successfully_and_is_brought_to_the_inventory_page() throws Exception {
            System.out.println("Navigate to next page");
        }
    
    }
```

TestNG Test Runner:

```
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;

import io.cucumber.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests;
import io.cucumber.testng.CucumberOptions;

@CucumberOptions(
        // Features
        features = "<feature file path>",

        // Glue
        glue = { "<step definition package name>" }, 
        plugin = { "json:target/reports/cucumber8.json",
                "rerun:target/rerun.txt" }, 
        tags = "not @smoke", 
        monochrome = true

)

    public class SauceDemoRunner extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests {
    
        @Override
        @DataProvider()
        public Object[][] scenarios() {
            return super.scenarios();
        }
    
    }
```

TestNG file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
    <suite name="Sauce Demo Cucumber Test Automation">
        <test thread-count="2" name="test" parallel="classes">
            <classes>
                <class name="runner file class path with package name" />
            </classes>
        </test> <!-- Test -->
    </suite> <!-- Suite -->
```